# D-Link DIR-850L QoS not working

Tags: router, bandwidth, latency, qos

Quality of Service is not working on my router.

My seedbox (Xios) is set to the lowest priority and does not get throttled as it should when any of the higher priority devices require more bandwidth, resulting in much higher latency in games.

I have tried various uplink and downlink speeds, and both queue types to no avail.

Is this a poor implementation on behalf of my router or am I misunderstanding QoS? I would like take advantage of my available bandwidth with my seedbox when the network is more vacant.

All of my IPs are statically served via DHCP and are within the correct ranges.

[image]

Comment: The "Application Port" under the "Classification Rules" - I guess this is an arbitrary text box where you can type in custom or preset rule definitions? What is in your "ALL" definition?

Comment: That is the default setting. I want the entire system throttled, not just p2p.

Comment: I have tried specifying the port for Transmission and lowering my uplink, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You may want to consider backing up the configuration and factory resetting the router and try the QoS settings from a clean slate...

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help. Before we start I want to apologize for my bad English. What are your speeds?

You should run speedtest with your computer connected directly to your modem at different times of the day. You should take note of the lowest ever values of speeds that you get. you should then use 85% of those values. This is important. Don't use your whole bandwidth as it will break QoS. Read this thread on the subject: http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/using-qos-tutorial-and-discussion.28349/

To sum it up, this is not real QoS. It's traffic shaping and you are doing it only at your end. Since you have limited control of your bandwidth, you must make sure no traffic ever gets queued at your ISP. The moment a queue is formed there, your ping will sky rocket.

The other issue is that Dlink QoS does not have default rules. This means that all devices must be in a rule somewhere. If you just set your seedbox to low priority it will not work. You must set some priority to all other devices in your network.

Are you on the latest firmware available? Check to see if there are any updates on the Dlink website.

Try these tips and get back to me if that doesn't work.

Edit: Looking at the image you poted, I think you should use Weighted Fair Queue instead of strict priority. I'm pretty certain it uses HTB under the hood.

Comment: I'm actually thinking about buying this router, but will only do so if the QoS is reliable. There a lot of router reviews on the Web but no one reviews QoS.

Comment: With speed test I got around 20-25 Mbps and tried a variety of combinations and none of them did the trick. I only needed QoS to manage uploads (non-ISP side) and that wasn't working at all. I have updated to the latest firmware. I was trying both Strict Priority and Weighted Fair Queues. This router is great if you don't need QoS! If you want QoS, I highly recommend looking for a dd-wrt (http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) and/or Tomato (http://tomato.groov.pl/?page_id=69) supported router since they seem to do a good job at supporting QoS.